# Why npm init is used in any JS projects?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Recently I started learning typescript and little new to NPM, wants know about why npm init is used. can anyone please explain real time example. and most importantly please don't say question is asked here, there i am not satisfied with those answers so i am asking again here.

$ npm init

Comment: npm init generates an initial package.json try it out

Comment: npm init and yarn init are used to make package.json file. there is also --yes flag to get ride of list of question. Surly you need to go long..

Comment: It means to run command `init` of the program npm. As for why you should use a JS package manager, google should give plenty of the "why"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Npm is package manager with npm repository (here you can search pacakges https://www.npmjs.com/). If you need to install anything you need `package.json` file, that is created by `npm init` (the packages are used so you don't need to write code that someone else was already written), You can write that file yourself and not need to call `npm init`. The `package.json` is needed when you still packages because npm write installed packages into that file (I think that if you call npm install it will also create that file). So you can use `npm install` on directory that don't have packages installed (no node_modules directory) and it will install them, that way you can share you project and don't need to share lot of files from packages only one file is needed and of course code for you app. This is especially importent if you use lot of packages.

Comment: Nicely Explained! thanks @jcubic

Answer (score 1):

`npm init` can convert an empty directory to an npm project by adding `package.json` into it.

Also, you can add meta info of the project to the `package.json` while creating it.

If you don't have package.json in a directory, and you trigger `npm install moduleName` at that directory path then module will be installed globally

Comment: It's not to convert to a type of project, it's a helper to initiate the file package.json. You can "convert" even if the directory is not empty